# QGIS Convert MTM coordinate reference system

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have X,Y coordinates that imported from csv file into QGIS and assigned WGS84 to the layer, when I open the attribute table and select Geometery $X it just shows the state X value and doesn't convert to lat/lng. Below is value of X,Y trying to convert.

294556.96,5039387.933

```
GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
 DATUM["D_WGS_1984",
 SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],
 PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
 UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]
PROJCS["NAD_1983_MTM_8",
 GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",
 DATUM["D_North_American_1983",
 SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],
 PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
 UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
 PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
 PARAMETER["False_Easting",304800.0],
 PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],
 PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-73.5],
 PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9999],
 PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],
 UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Assigning a CRS does **NOT** reproject the coordinates.

Assuming X and Y are in the Canadian CRS you gave, you have to assign that to the CSV file. [EPSG:32188](http://www.spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/nad83-mtm-zone-8/) should be the right one.

Then use `Save As ...` to a different filename and EPSG:4326 as new CRS.